# Celery AsyncResult with Redis BackendResult Strange behaviour

Tags: python, celery

I ran an asynchronous task with celery; I use redis as Backend and MessageQueue.
I try to get the stored result through a new AsyncResult object, but it hangs..

My run :

```
>>> from test_celery.tasks import add
>>> from celery.result import AsyncResult
>>> r = add.delay(1,1)
>>> r.id
'71bfc569-5752-4535-8a9e-108a80157a1d'
>>> r.backend
<celery.backends.redis.RedisBackend object at 0x7f4242feb0d0>
>>> r.get()  
2
>>> r.get()
2
>>> x = AsyncResult(r.id)
>>> x.get()
--> hangs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me ;-)

my celery was set up to keep results 5 seconds ...

```
app.conf.update(result_expires=5,)
```